# Allow a certain server to only be able to redirect to a php page

Tags: php, node.js, heroku

This may be a question someone has already asked. (If it is I'm sorry, I could not find another question like this.)
I designed a webapp on PHP-NODEJS-Static HTML. I send a form from the static HTML to the NODEJS app to get approved. If approved I want the nodejs application to redirect to a php page. I already have the nodejs application up on heroku, and it is designed so if it is approved, it automatically redirects to a php page. The problem is that I only want the redirects from the server to be able to display the php page if that makes any sense. How do I go around doing this.

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that you want to restrict access to this "php page" ONLY to visitors who are being redirected?  If so, you might want to phrase it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have your nodejs, before redirecting, create a secure one-time token. The token should be embedded into the URL pointing to the PHP server (the one that the browsers will follow for redirect), and stored in a database (probably associated with an expiration, umm, say 5 minutes?).

When PHP page receives the request, it should extract the token from the URL, and validate whether the token exists, and only proceed further then. PHP page should also remove the token once used. You will need some sort of a database to store the token, I would recommend Redis, as it has an automatic expiration of keys, so you don't have to worry about clean up, or clogged database.